# storing sum of each subset of array separately not the total sum of all subsets

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, subset

I have an array a[]={1,2,3} and I want separate sum of all possible combination of these elements i.e; 1,2,3,1+2,1+3,2+3,1+2+3(separately not the total sum of all subsets) in O(n) complexity and the array can even have more than 3 elements too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int timewaste(int a[],int i,int sum,int l)
{
    sum= sum + a[i];
    printf("%d\n\n",sum);
    if(i==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        timewaste(a,i,sum,l);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,n,a[50],y,t,pehlibaar;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;--i)
    {
        pehlibaar=0;
        timewaste(a,i,pehlibaar,1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the link to the image in a diagram of what I am trying to do with recursion http://uploadpie.com/dQpQp

Comment: So you have a requirement, you have some code, you've posted here.  Does your code work?  Do you expect it to?  If not, what does it do?  What inputs did you provide?  What outputs did you get?  What don't you understand about fixing whatever's wrong?

Comment: nothings wrong it implements is there any other method so that i can improve its running time..

Comment: http://uploadpie.com/OVfwQ
it uses recursion gives for example a[]={1,2,3}
then it gives output    3

Comment: http://uploadpie.com/OVfwQ
it uses recursion gives for example a[]={1,2,3}
then it gives output    3,    5  ,      6         ,4,     2,    3,     1
                                 {3},{3+2 },{3+2+1},{3+1}{2},{2+1},{1}

Comment: newbie into stackoverflow i dont have much idea yat abt how to ask questions on stackoverflow

Comment: That isn't what this code outputs, [given input of 3, then 1 2 3](http://ideone.com/PR4MD6). So your statement "nothings wrong" seems to be rather optimistic.

Comment: i will just edit and post the whole working code...

Comment: The problem is not solvable in linear time. Any algorithm will take at least Omega(2^n) time to solve it. See my answer below.

Comment: Please don't deface posts @AkashMahalik that includes titles, and it includes posts you've made. They are part of the community once posted, and we would like to keep our site clean of trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that since there are `2^n` different subarrays you could in the worst case have `2^n` different sums (this happens when elements are sufficiently far apart)---and you want to store all of them explicitly. So there is no way to solve the problem in linear time; this is because you have to "touch" each of the `2^n` sums in order to store them; this means you will have to make at least `2^n` operations just to visit all of the sums. It will take `O(2^n)` time in the worst case. (More precisely, we have `Omega(2^n)` lower bound on the running time.)

As far as the algorithm is concerned, why don't you start with the whole sum and then keep subtracting away. Here's the pseudocode for an algorithm.

```
array = {1, 2, ..., 3} // array of size n
subtracted = {false, false, ..., false}
sum = array[0]+array[1]+...+array[n-1]
visitedArray= {} // hashtable that tels whether we've visited a given array
void all_sums(array, subtracted, sum) {
     // If we've already seen the array, do nothing
     if (visitedArray[array]) return;
     // otherwise, process it
     print sum
     // Remember that we've visited the array, so we don't repeat unnecessary work         
     visitedArray[array] = true;
    // process the current sum---e.g. store wherever you want
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (!subtracted[i]) {
            subtracted[i] = true;
            all_sums(array, subtracted, sum-array[i])
            subtracted[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I use `visiedArray` is to avoid computing the same sum in different ways, such as the `1` that we get by first subtracting away 3 and then 2 and the `1` we get by first subtracting away 2 and then 3. (If don't prune away these the running time becomes something like `O(n! * 2^n)`.)

Comment: will this improve my running time complexity ??

Comment: Now it uses additional hashtable to remember which arrays it has seen already and can thus avoid doing unnecessary work.

Comment: gives output : 6 5 3 0 2 0 4 3 0 1 0 3 2 0 1 0 for input of 3 and then 1,2,3
NOT SHOWING THE output which i want link to the code https://ideone.com/Qwszmh

Comment: It gives the correct output; some of the work is repeating; you avoid that using a hashtable that remembers which arrays it visited already.

Comment: One way to do it is to use `std::map<std::vector<int>, bool> seen`, that is, you use a `std::vector<int>` instead of an array of `int`s.

Comment: i dont have idea abt vectors use in programming yet

Comment: where should i declare visitedArray = {} and how.. would be very helpful. thanks in advance :)

Comment: here's the link to code where should i actually declare visitedarray
https://ideone.com/Qwszmh

Comment: @AkashMahalik here's a C++ code that should work: https://ideone.com/L0lOri

Comment: it still prints an extra zero?? except that all other outputs are correct

Comment: Yes, zero is the sum of the empty subarray, which technically is a subarray. I believe it's mathematically correct to print the zero.

Comment: @AkashMahalik if you don't want the extra zero, you can do additional check whether all entries in the array `subtracted` are false,and don't print the `sum` in that case.

Comment: @AkashMahalik is this what you wanted?

Comment: thanks :)
can we have a chat ? :D

Comment: Yes. You can write me at blaz.sovdat@gmail.com

Comment: :D i will get in touch

Comment: @AkashMahalik can I delete the code from the answer? I don't think it's a well-written code and we should either improve it or remove it; we don't want to encourage people to write poor code (it's my fault; I hacked it together).

Comment: yup u can i have the code but,i have a new issue with that problem :P
what if i have the array 1,2,3,4,5
but i want separate sum of subsets from particular 2nd position to 4thposition that means now my new array would be 2,3,4

Comment: hey another issue sorry :( when i input array of 2,2,3 the output is  7,5,3,2,4 whereas it should be 3,5,5,7,2,4,2 !!

Comment: Ooops, I will check it later.

Comment: @AkashMahalik ah, yes, do you want to allow sums to duplicate? In the code I convert each array into a canonical form (by sorting the array) and then print the sum only if I haven't seen that array; I do this in order to avoid duplicating the output. I purposefuly print 5 and 2 only once.

Comment: what to change if i want to duplicate sums ?? like that for array 2,2,3 it should print 3,5,5,7,2,4,2

Comment: @AkashMahalik I now differentiate between the same elements by recording their positions: https://ideone.com/QFROGY Does this work as you'd like it to?

Comment: wow u r so awesome :D thnx

Comment: is there any way i can mark the end of recursion and return to main program ??

Comment: Yes, simply say return; in the recursive function; however you must specify that in terms of conditions on variables available to you in the function.

Comment: what if i want to send 1 array 1,2,3 and then another array 2,2,3 will it give the proper sum for the second array ??

Comment: Ah, yes, you should clear the "cache" between consecutive calls to the function. Simply say `visitedArray.clear();`

Comment: where should i add this ?

Comment: In the main, before each call to the function `all_sum`: `visitedArray.clear(); all_sum(...); ...`

Comment: u can delete the code:D

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `for(i=i-1;i>=l;i--)` to `for(i=i-1;i>=0;i--)`

Comment: i had it done actually i but my mistake thanks